# How to replicate ShellExecuteEx failure with ERROR_NO_ASSOCIATION error?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-shell, shellexecute, shellexecuteex

My application displays a report to its end-users by composing it into an `.htm` file that is placed into a user's temp folder (that is derived by calling `GetTempPath` API). It is then shown to the user with the code as such:

```
//strCmd == file:///C:/Users/UserName/AppData/Local/Temp/My_Report.htm

SHELLEXECUTEINFO sei = {0};
sei.cbSize = sizeof(sei);
sei.fMask = SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI;
sei.nShow = SW_SHOW;
sei.lpVerb = L"open";
sei.lpFile = strCmd.GetBuffer();
sei.hwnd = hParentWnd;

BOOL bInitialized = SUCCEEDED(CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE));

if(ShellExecuteEx(&sei))
{
    //Success
}
else
{
    //Failed
    REPORT_ERROR(GetLastError());
}

if(bInitialized)
{
    CoUninitialize();
}
```

I just got a bug report from a customer that shows that the code above reports `ERROR_NO_ASSOCIATION`. The OS from the picture I got looks like Windows 8.1, or maybe Windows 7.

So I've been trying to replicate it in a VM by removing all file associations for the `.htm` and `.html` file extensions, but `ShellExecuteEx` never seems to fail. On Windows 10 it always opens up Edge and on Win 8.1 it showed this popup:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can replicate that error?

Comment: Don't use "open" as the verb (as this verb may not be defined); instead, use `nullptr` to get the default action.

Answer (score 0):

Removing .htm[l] probably has no effect because file:// is a protocol so you probably have to remove it as well.

You should try to remove `HKCR\file`.

This is as far as the documentation can take you but there are other undocumented keys involved in the default association selection.

For file extensions you need to remove `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.htm` (or as a minimum, the UserChoice subkey)

and for protocols you need to remove `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\file`. This key can exist under HKLM as well.

There might be other keys involved, you can find out where Windows looks by monitoring your application with Process Monitor from SysInternals.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately I don't remember now what my conclusion was on that topic. I think I ended up calling `AssocQueryString(ASSOCF_INIT_IGNOREUNKNOWN, ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE)` on the file extension and if it returned nothing, I'd show a user warning that there's no association with `html` files. Otherwise it's hard to know [how else MS will screw up file association settings in the next "November feature update"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20181016-00/?p=99985).