# how to use the SHCreateAssociationRegistration to set ProgId for the app for file Association

Tags: c

I want to association file in win 10, I want to use IApplicationAssociationRegistrationInternal::SetAppAsDefault() ,but it does not support after win 8.

I see a user Castorix say he tested on Windows 10 - 1803, 17134.820 is OK, But I does not know how to write the code.

This is the answer of Castorix :

On Windows 10, it is done with IApplicationAssociationRegistrationInternal ("2a848e25-d688-4aa3-8e55-0c16cb3a2dfb")

created with SHCreateAssociationRegistration

Set "AppX4hxtad77fbk3jkkeerkrm0ze94wjf3s9" for Microsoft Edge ProgId

(tested on Windows 10 - 1803, 17134.820)

I WANT TO GET THE COMPLETE CODE, WHO CAN HELP ME, THANKS!

Comment: Hello @jiafu and welcome on Stack Overflow. Could you please give the link of the answer or comment by Castorix you are refering to ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52862676/how-to-set-up-microsoft-edge-file-association-to-open-htm-files/56612618#56612618